# Vimeo API - Console errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, vimeo, vimeo-api

Hey guys i'm trying to make a custom video slider for a page just noticed everytime it slides 5 errors appear in my console:

> Ungaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at 1 (frogaloop2.min.js)
>   Ungaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at 1 (frogaloop2.min.js)
>   Ungaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at 1 (frogaloop2.min.js)
>   Ungaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at 1 (frogaloop2.min.js)
>   GET https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?callback=vimeoCallback&url=https://vimeo/undefined net::ERR_ABORTED

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var iframe = document.getElementById("video");
    var player = $f(iframe);
    var playButton = document.getElementById("play-button");
    var interval = null;
    
    var videoCover = [
    "http://res.cloudinary.com/dii2nxgkh/image/upload/v1505311262/123_eihw5x.jpg",
    "http://res.cloudinary.com/dii2nxgkh/image/upload/v1505312273/2_vcxdhc.jpg",
    "http://res.cloudinary.com/dii2nxgkh/image/upload/v1505312273/3_ignkr9.jpg",
    "http://res.cloudinary.com/dii2nxgkh/image/upload/v1505312273/4_lpbars.jpg"
    ];

    var videos = [
  "https://player.vimeo.com/video/161138986?api=1",
  "https://player.vimeo.com/video/161901908?api=1",
  "https://player.vimeo.com/video/75736121?api=1",
  "https://player.vimeo.com/video/184564192?api=1"
    ];
    var headings = [
  "Introducing Mobile Answering",
  "Introducing Slide Two",
  "Introducing Slide Three",
  "Introducing Slide Four"
    ];
    var slideText = [
  "Slide 1 dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus fringilla at ex sit amet viverra. Duis sapien lorem, bibendum nec augue gravida, vestibulum maximus lorem. Nam scelerisque nec massa quis dictum. Etiam id imperdiet dolor.",
  "Slide 2 dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus fringilla at ex sit amet viverra. Duis sapien lorem, bibendum nec augue gravida, vestibulum maximus lorem. Nam scelerisque nec massa quis dictum. Etiam id imperdiet dolor.",
  "Slide 3 dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus fringilla at ex sit amet viverra. Duis sapien lorem, bibendum nec augue gravida, vestibulum maximus lorem. Nam scelerisque nec massa quis dictum. Etiam id imperdiet dolor.",
  "Slide 4 dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus fringilla at ex sit amet viverra. Duis sapien lorem, bibendum nec augue gravida, vestibulum maximus lorem. Nam scelerisque nec massa quis dictum. Etiam id imperdiet dolor."
    ];
    var bgColor = ["#182853", "#ce0e5c", "#ed7a0b", "#c72539"];

    var slideCount = 0;

    $(".vidslider li").find(".right").css("background", bgColor[slideCount]);
    $(".vidslider li").find(".left img").attr("src", videoCover[slideCount]);
    $(".vidslider li").find(".left .embed-container iframe").attr("src", videos[slideCount]);
    $(".vidslider li").find(".right h2").text(headings[slideCount]);
    $(".vidslider li").find(".right p").text(slideText[slideCount]);
    $(".vidslider li").find(".counter").append("<span>1</span> of " + videoCover.length);

    $(".next").click(function () {
        var slide = $(".vidslider li");
        slideCount++;

        if (slideCount >= videoCover.length) {
            slideCount = 0;
        }

        $(slide).find(".right h2").fadeOut(300);
        $(slide).find(".right p").fadeOut(300);

        setTimeout(function () {
            $(slide).find(".right").addClass("activeVid");
            $(slide).find(".left").addClass("hide");
            $(slide).find(".right").css("background", bgColor[slideCount]);
            $(slide).find(".vidClose").css("background", bgColor[slideCount]);
        }, 350);

        setTimeout(function () {
            $(slide).find(".right").removeClass("activeVid");
            $(slide).find(".left").removeClass("hide");
            $(".counter span").html(slideCount + 1);
            $(slide).find(".right h2").text(headings[slideCount]);
            $(slide).find(".right p").text(slideText[slideCount]);
            $(slide).find(".left img").attr("src", videoCover[slideCount]);
            $(slide).find(".left .embed-container iframe").attr("src", videos[slideCount]);
        }, 1050);

        setTimeout(function () {
            $(slide).find(".right h2").fadeIn(300);
            $(slide).find(".right p").fadeIn(300);
        }, 1600);
    });

    $(".prev").click(function () {
        var slide = $(".vidslider li");
        slideCount--;

        if (slideCount < 0) {
            slideCount = videoCover.length - 1;
        }

        $(slide).find(".right h2").fadeOut(300);
        $(slide).find(".right p").fadeOut(300);

        setTimeout(function () {
            $(slide).find(".right").addClass("activeVid");
            $(slide).find(".left").addClass("hide");
            $(slide).find(".right").css("background", bgColor[slideCount]);
            $(slide).find(".vidClose").css("background", bgColor[slideCount]);
        }, 350);

        setTimeout(function () {
            $(slide).find(".right").removeClass("activeVid");
            $(slide).find(".left").removeClass("hide");
            $(".counter span").html(slideCount + 1);
            $(slide).find(".right h2").text(headings[slideCount]);
            $(slide).find(".right p").text(slideText[slideCount]);
            $(slide).find(".left img").attr("src", videoCover[slideCount]);
            $(slide)
    .find(".left .embed-container iframe")
    .attr("src", videos[slideCount]);
        }, 1050);

        setTimeout(function () {
            $(slide).find(".right h2").fadeIn(300);
            $(slide).find(".right p").fadeIn(300);
        }, 1600);
    });

    $(".left").click(function () {
        var slide = $(".vidslider li");
        player.api("play");

        $(this).addClass("activeVid");
        $(slide).find(".right").addClass("hide");
        $(this).find("img").css("width", "100%");
        $(".controls").fadeOut(300);
        $(".counter").fadeOut(300);
        $(".left .overlayVid").fadeOut(300);
        $(".left img").fadeOut(300);

        setTimeout(function () {
            $(slide).find(".right").fadeOut(300);
        }, 600);
    });

    $(".pullTab, .vidClose").click(function () {
        var slide = $(".vidslider li");
        player.api("unload");

        $(slide).find(".right").fadeIn(200);
        $(".controls").fadeIn(200);
        $(".counter").fadeIn(200);

        $(".left").removeClass("activeVid");
        $(slide).find(".right").removeClass("hide");
        $(".left").find("img").css("width", "120%");
        $(".left .overlayVid").fadeIn(300);
        $(".left img").fadeIn(300);
    });

    $(function () {
        interval = setInterval(callFunc, 7000);
    });

    function callFunc() {
        jQuery(".next").trigger("click");
    }

    $(".vidslider").hover(function () {
        clearInterval(interval);
    });



    $(".vidslider").on("mouseleave", function () {
        if ($('.left').hasClass('activeVid')) {
            console.log('Video open');
        } else {
            interval = setInterval(callFunc, 7000);
        }
    });


});
```

```css
.cf:before {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.cf:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#sliderHowTo {
  width: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin: 60px 0;
  overflow: inherit !important;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
#sliderHowTo h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #562d4d;
  line-height: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300!important;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}
#sliderHowTo .vidslider {
  max-width: 760px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px;
}
#sliderHowTo .vidslider li {
  height: 428px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#sliderHowTo .vidslider li .left {
  width: 67%;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
  -o-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
  min-height: 428px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  will-change: auto;
}
#sliderHowTo .vidslider li .left img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  will-change: auto;
}
#sliderHowTo .vidslider li .left.hide {
  width: 0%;
}
#sliderHowTo .vidslider li .left .embed-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
}
#sliderHowTo .vidslider li .left .embed-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#sliderHowTo .vidslider li .left .embed-container object {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#sliderHowTo .vidslider li .left .embed-container embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#sliderHowTo .vidslider li .left .overlayVid {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 428px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
#sliderHowTo .vidslider li .left .overlayVid:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#sliderHowTo .vidslider li .left .overlayVid:after {
  content: '';
  background: url("http://svgshare.com/i/307.svg");
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#sliderHowTo .vidslider li .left.activeVid {
  width: 100%;
}
#sliderHowTo .vidslider li .right {
  width: 33.33%;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 25px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 50%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: #182853;
  min-height: 428px;
  z-index: 5;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
  -o-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  padding-top: 65px;
  will-change: auto;
}
#sliderHowTo .vidslider li .right h2 {
  font-size: 22px;
  width: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
}
#sliderHowTo .vidslider li .right p {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
}
#sliderHowTo .vidslider li .right.activeVid {
  width: 100%;
}
#sliderHowTo .vidslider li .right.hide {
  width: 0%;
  padding-left: 0;
}
#sliderHowTo .vidslider li .counter {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 24px;
  right: 55px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 11px;
  z-index: 10;
}
#sliderHowTo .vidslider li .controls {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 15px;
  z-index: 10;
}
#sliderHowTo .vidslider li .controls .next {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  background: url("/assets/images/misc/arrowNext.svg");
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  will-change: auto;
}
#sliderHowTo .vidslider li .controls .next:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
#sliderHowTo .vidslider li .controls .prev {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  background: url("/assets/images/misc/arrowBack.svg");
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 40px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  will-change: auto;
}
#sliderHowTo .vidslider li .controls .prev:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
#sliderHowTo .vidslider li .pullTab {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #182853;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: -20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50% 0% 0% 50%;
  border-radius: 50% 0% 0% 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
#sliderHowTo .vidslider li .pullTab:hover {
  right: -17px;
}
#sliderHowTo .vidslider li .pullTab:after {
  background: url("http://svgshare.com/i/32U.svg") no-repeat;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#sliderHowTo .vidslider li .vidClose {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background: #182853;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0% 0% 0% 50%;
  border-radius: 0% 0% 0% 50%;
}
#sliderHowTo .vidslider li .vidClose:after {
  background: url("http://svgshare.com/i/353.svg") no-repeat;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  top: 45%;
  left: 55%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="sliderHowTo" class="cf">
    <h1>How-to videos</h1>

    <ul class="vidslider">
        <li class="cf">
            <div class="left">
                <div id="play-button" class="overlayVid"></div>
                <img class="videoCover" src="">
                <div class='embed-container'>
                    <iframe id="video" src='' frameborder='0' webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <h2></h2>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="prev"></div>
                <div class="next"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="counter"></div>
            <div class="vidClose"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

And a link to codepen where it seems to be working fine: https://codepen.io/nsmed/pen/oGNgxp

I'm guessing its something to do with the way i'm inserting the src for each video when it slides.

Comment: What does this have to do with the StackOverflow API?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with the Stack Overflow API, but your title reads "Stack overflow API - Console errors". Is this a mistake? If yes, please fix it by editing your question.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [uncompressed version](https://github.com/tanepiper/vimeo-froogaloop2/tree/master/javascript) of the `froogaloop` library.

There are some issues if you dont assign a unique id for the video player element. Each player must have its unique id.

`<iframe id='vimeo-player' src='link-for-vimeo?api=1&player_id=vimeo-player'></iframe>`

Here is an example:

```js
$(function() {
    var iframe = $('#player1')[0];
    var player = $f(iframe);
    var status = $('.status');

    // When the player is ready, add listeners for pause, finish, and playProgress
    player.addEvent('ready', function() {
        status.text('ready');
        
        player.addEvent('pause', onPause);
        player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
        player.addEvent('playProgress', onPlayProgress);
    });

    // Call the API when a button is pressed
    $('button').bind('click', function() {
        player.api($(this).text().toLowerCase());
    });

    function onPause() {
        status.text('paused');
    }

    function onFinish() {
        status.text('finished');
    }

    function onPlayProgress(data) {
        status.text(data.seconds + 's played');
    }
});
```

```css
div {
  margin-top: 3px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

button {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 8px 18px 10px;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #fff;
  background: #345;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 0.75em;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://f.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="player1" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871?api=1&player_id=player1" width="630" height="354" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

<div>
  <button>Play</button>
  <button>Pause</button>
  <p>Status: <span class="status">&hellip;</span></p>
</div>
```